# recv() always return 1

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I have a client-server that needs stay connected. So I'm really confused about when to stop receiving data. The recv() always return 1. And while() can't stop!

```
    int nbytes = 0;
    char buf_to_parse[4096] = { '\0' };
    char saveAll[20480] = { '\0' }; 

    while ((nbytes = recv(wParam, buf_to_parse , 4096 , 0) != 0)) //nbytes is always 1
    {
        sprintf_s(saveAll, "%s%s", saveAll, buf_to_parse);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are doing a comparison and that is cast into an integer. When you say

```
nbytes = recv(wParam, buf_to_parse , 4096 , 0) != 0
```

because of operator presedence it means

```
nbytes = (recv(wParam, buf_to_parse , 4096 , 0) != 0)
```

which just tests if the return value of `recv()` is not zero and puts false or true (0 or 1 by convention) into `nbytes`. What you want is

```
(nbytes = recv(wParam, buf_to_parse , 4096 , 0)) > 0
```

This will set the number of bytes into nbytes and then compare the value. You must also take into account negative values in error conditions, not only the zero which is only given on proper disconnection.

The code you had would have worked for the `while` if the closing is done properly, but `nbytes` would've been wrong anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such a little mistake!